# Load images onto a report dynamically in Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I load images dynamically in place of cell data in a report in Oracle Application Express?

E.g.

A table has 'Y' and 'N' entries. When I display it as a report, I want to use certain images according to the data in the table. If it's a 'Y', display one image and if it's a 'N', display another image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select id, 
       htf.img (case when flag='Y' then 'yesicon.png'
                                   else 'noicon.png' end) flag_icon
from   mytable
where  ...
```

You probably need to add a path for the filenames e.g. '#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#yesicon.png' etc.

If you will be using this a lot it would be worth building a function to simplify it:

```
select id, 
       mypkg.yesno_icon (flag) flag_icon
from   mytable
where  ...
```